# Unexpected Indent Error

Tags: python, indentation

```
import re
import xlwt

book = xlwt.Workbook()
sheet = book.add_sheet("Run sheet")

ifile = open("invoices.txt",'r')

# Read file object to string
text = ifile.read()

m1 = re.findall(r"From(?s)(.*?)Mobile", text)
m2 = re.findall(r"Mobile :(?s)(.*)Prokure", text)
x=0;
for i in m1:
    sheet.write(0,x, i)
    x+=1
book.save("runsheet.xls")
```

This code gives me an indentation error for x+=1

Please could ou help me out. New to python

Comment: 4 spaces versus tab?

Comment: Using a text editor which auto indents

Comment: If you've edited the file written by someone else in a different machine, the previous indent might be different than your editor's auto indentation method. Just copy the indent part of previous line and add it before `x=x+1`.

Comment: Where is `x=x+1`?  i don't see it anywhere.

Comment: Its giving me the same error if i add a counter in any of the loops. It shows unexpected indent.

Answer (score 1):

It could be the result of mixing tabs and spaces. You should convert indentation to either spaces only or to tabs only. Sublime text can do that for you.

In **Notepad++** : Settings->Preferences->Language Menu/Tab Settings->"Replace by space"

Comment: i am using notepad++ which auto indents everything. The error is coming as 'unexpected indent' for every counter i try to add to any loop.

Comment: Try this: Settings->Preferences->Language Menu/Tab Settings->"Replace by space"